# Swipe cell to delete show two buttons but need one

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have TableView with a custom UITableViewCells, and when i swipe cell, to show button, i get two Buttons like this - 
[image]

But need one button - "Delete"...
What i do wrong?
Cell is Custom...but i do not add gray button.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood. I did't see, what i added not documented function, which are for second button -

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForSwipeAccessoryButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
return @"";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` in the delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```